# Android Build Tools Gradle 2.3.2

Tags: android, gradle, jcenter

The dependency `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2` does not exists on `jcenter`.

Why is that ? I had the update yesterday on Android Studio :/

Comment: same problem, via IDE compiling works fine, but via gradle console not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They mixed something up in the update - Studio rollout done, jcenter update forgotten.
Yes, Android Studio rolls out the update and suggests to upgrade to 2.3.2 and you are right, this version is not yet available at jcenter.
For now, manually put 2.3.1 in your build file and check back every other day if the new version can be downloaded...

Should not happen, shame on you, DevTeam :)

Comment: Also not sure if they will update the repo with 2.3.2 as I can see 2.4.0 alphas and 2.5.0 alpha preview after 2.3.1

Answer (score 2):

This morning was failing too, but now seems to be working.

Here's the Bintray link: https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Hm not sure 2.3.2 is out yet. Try downgrading to 2.3.1

Comment: Android Studio asked me to update it yesterday... :/

Comment: is strangely, via console not works but via IDE works well